seperate data from a single request.security
//@version=5
indicator("FREC", overlay=true)
my_table = table.new(position = position.bottom_center, columns = 5, rows = 5, bgcolor = color.white, frame_color = color.black, border_color = color.red, frame_width = 20, border_width = 20)
symbol_name = syminfo.ticker
last_1440m_price = request.security(symbol_name, "1440", close)
table.cell_set_text_color(my_table,0,0,text_color = color.black)
table.cell_set_text_color(my_table,1,0,text_color = color.black)
table.cell_set_text_color(my_table,2,0,text_color = color.black)
table.cell_set_text(my_table, 0, 0, str.tostring(last_1440m_price[0], "#.##") + "%")
table.cell_set_text(my_table, 1, 0, str.tostring(last_1440m_price[360], "#.##") + "%")
table.cell_set_text(my_table, 2, 0, str.tostring(last_1440m_price[720], "#.##") + "%")

I just want to have an access for last 1440 min data and then get the close values of first minute 360 minute and 720 minute of that interval but I need to do this with a single request.security. it is fine when I try use request.security three times but it does not work with a single request.security. the values that I get do not match with the values which has to be and yes my chart is also set for 1m timeframe while I am trying.
I am trying to get last 1440 minute data and then try to access close values of candle's which I want

I think you misunderstand what request.security() does. When calling '1440' as the timeframe, you're getting a single 1440-minute candle. You will not be able to access lower timeframe data in that candle.
If your results are fine with three request.security() calls, you must settle for that. There are no workarounds for this situation.

thank you for your answer. I just want to make sure that there is no way to get more than one candle information with a single request am I right?

It is like this: You got a 1440-minute candle with your original request.security() call. When you ask for last_1440m_price[360], that is looking at a candle that was 518400 minutes ago (360 trading days ago).
